# React leaflet heatmap layer v3 update issue on pinch zoom

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, react-leaflet

I am facing an update issue for [react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3) while pinch zoom in mobile as shown in the image. how to update the heatmap layer accordingly?

[image]

I expect to update heatmap layer as map updates